# How to change a class member in a method declared as const

Tags: c++, constants

I have a class which gives value for a corresponding time. I have a method that changes the `m_time` **(in hh,mm,ss)[ms]** but is declared as `const` at the end. So I need to change the attribute `m_time` but I can't ! how could I possibly go around this?

Here is my code:

```cpp
class CMeasurementValue
{
private:
    double m_value;
    unsigned int m_time;

public:
    CMeasurementValue(double value=0,unsigned int time=0);
    CMeasurementValue(double value,unsigned int hh,unsigned int mm , double ss);
    double getValue() const ;
    unsigned int getTime() const;
    void calculateTime(unsigned int& hh , unsigned int& mm , double& ss ) const;
    bool operator <(const CMeasurementValue& rop)const ;
    friend ostream& operator <<( ostream& out, const CMeasurementValue& rop);
    void print();
};

void CMeasurementValue::calculateTime(unsigned int& hh , unsigned int& mm , double& ss) const
{
    // ??
}
```

Comment: You cannot change class members without either removing `const` from method or making that member `mutable`. But are you sure you should edit any member? My intuition suggests that method `calculateTime` should take whatever is currently stored in the class and based on that calculate `hh`, `mm` and `ss` (and return those value to caller via output parameters). You should probably ask whoever gave you constraints what they meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare your member `m_time` [`mutable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) like this:

```cpp
class CMeasurementValue {
private:
    double m_value;
    mutable unsigned int m_time;
    // ...
};
```

From the docs:

> - mutable - permits modification of the class member declared mutable
>     even if the containing object is declared const.

However, if the function `calculateTime`, which is marked as `const`, is supposed to change the state of one of the members, why is it then marked as `const`?

Comment: it was a header from an exam , it was declared like that . i think it's more like a security or something like that . the question is if i change the declaration to mutable  what's effect has that on the attribut ?

Comment: like you said guys i missunterstood the purpose of the methode , the purpose is to calculate the m_time [ms] iin hh,mm,ss ! so the purpose is not to change the attribut m_time but to extract the information (hh,mm,ss ) from it , that's explain also why the parameter is as Ref& declared ! thank you very much guys , i learned at least what mutable make

Comment: @AhmedLadhibi no problem really, I am glad I helped you